# Perl multiline replace with spaces / using regular expression

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to replace

```
 <!--
    <env-entry>
       <env-entry-name>solr/home</env-entry-name>
       <env-entry-value>/put/your/solr/home/here</env-entry-value>
       <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
    </env-entry>
  -->
```

from a shell script. Therefore I am trying to use perl with the command

```
sudo perl -0777 -i -pe 's:<!--\n *<env-entry>\n *<env-entry-name>solr/home</env-entry-name>\n *<env-entry-value>/put/your/solr/home/here</env-entry-value>\n *<env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>\n *</env-entry>\n *-->:<env-entry>\n <env-entry-name>solr/home</env-entry-name>\n <env-entry-value>/home/solr</env-entry-value>\n <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>\n </env-entry>:g' /usr/share/tomcat6/webapps/solr/WEB-INF/web.xml
```

According to [this regex test page](http://www.regexr.com) it should work but for some reason calling the command from terminal doesn't work.

**Edit:**

```
sudo perl -0777 -i -pe 's:<!--\n 
 *<env-entry>\n 
 *<env-entry-name>solr/home</env-entry-name>\n 
 *<env-entry-value>/put/your/solr/home/here</env-entry-value>\n 
 *<env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>\n 
 *</env-entry>\n 
 *-->:
 <env-entry>\n 
 <env-entry-name>solr/home</env-entry-name>\n 
 <env-entry-value>/home/solr</env-entry-value>\n 
 <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>\n 
 </env-entry>:g' /usr/share/tomcat6/webapps/solr/WEB-INF/web.xml
```

Comment: Why on earth would you try to do a multi-line match like that in a single line?  Do you just like (insist on) making life hard for yourself? And showing a `sudo` on a command still under development, and using `-i`, shows scant regard for the sanity of your system.  You don't screw around with root privileges until you know it will work.  You test and develop using non-root privileges, and only when you've done everything you can to ensure it is bullet-proof do you even think about running it as root. Even then, do non-destructive testing before finally, reluctantly, clobbering the file.

Comment: Oh I'm testing this only on a virtual client (using vagrant) and have even backed up the file - so no worries about the root privileges!

Comment: Worry about the root privileges even so; it is cultivating dangerous habits, and dangerous habits remain dangerous even when you've got virtual clients, etc.  One day, you'll do the changes and find you weren't in a backed up virtual client and you just screwed up the production system.  It simply isn't safe to get comfortable doing development as root.

Comment: Okay thanks for the input, I try to respect this for future development . But my problem exists either way!

Comment: Yes; and you can even do it as root, and overwrite the original file before you know the script works in private; just don't show your bad habits on SO.  :D  (That requires you to know they're bad habits, of course.) I'm not willing to look at your regex; it is unreadable because it is on one line.  You could use `\s` instead of spaces which would handle tabs too.  You don't seem to have `-->` matched in it, but I may have missed that — it is, as I said, wholly unreadable, so I'm not going to spend time reading it.

Comment: I guess I am rather going to try to not use it untested as a root, anymore. And even more not to post it here ;) I added some linebreaks to the command for readability!

Comment: Think you're missing `x` modifier

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given a data file called `data`:

```
blah blah blah
 <!--
    <env-entry>
       <env-entry-name>solr/home</env-entry-name>
       <env-entry-value>/put/your/solr/home/here</env-entry-value>
       <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
    </env-entry>
  -->
blah blah more blah
```

and a shell script `xx.sh` containing:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's:<!--\n 
\s*<env-entry>\n 
\s*<env-entry-name>solr/home</env-entry-name>\n 
\s*<env-entry-value>/put/your/solr/home/here</env-entry-value>\n 
\s*<env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>\n 
\s*</env-entry>\n 
\s*-->:
 <env-entry>
     <env-entry-name>solr/home</env-entry-name>
         <env-entry-value>/home/solr</env-entry-value>
     <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
 </env-entry>
:gx' "$@"
```

The output from running `bash xx.sh data` is:

```
blah blah blah

 <env-entry>
     <env-entry-name>solr/home</env-entry-name>
         <env-entry-value>/home/solr</env-entry-value>
     <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
 </env-entry>

blah blah more blah
```

The key changes in the script are:

1. Remove `sudo`; as already indicated, I regard it as extremely unsafe to run untested code as `root`, even in a backed up virtualized development environment.  There is too much danger of making a mistake one day and finding that you weren't in the backed up virtualized environment this time.  You need to be very cautious as root.
2. Remove the `-i` so that files are not modified until the script is known to be working.
3. Add the all-important `x` qualifier to the regex; this means it uses extended formatting in which white space is not significant.
4. Because of the `x` qualifier, the space matching changed from `*` (blank-star) to `\s*`.
5. What I copied and pasted had trailing blanks in the replacement text lines, so that the `\n` was followed by a blank, effectively at the start of the next line.  I also indented the text a little more (the `<env-entry-value>` line) so it is easy to see that the regex was effective.

---

> But, unfortunately, if I try this with my file it doesn't work. If I copy/paste the part from my file below the content of your data file, it looks [like this](http://pastebin.com/gPtLZRVD). I can't find any difference but executing the shell script only the top one gets replaced.

After checking the file, using copy'n'paste from the Pastebin, there is a blank after the `<!--` that causes the failure.  The matching regex needs to be modified to handle that.  The way I'd do it is with non-greedy space matching (`\s*?`) at the ends of the lines:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's:<!--\s*?\n 
\s*<env-entry>\s*?\n 
\s*<env-entry-name>solr/home</env-entry-name>\s*?\n 
\s*<env-entry-value>/put/your/solr/home/here</env-entry-value>\s*?\n 
\s*<env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>\s*?\n 
\s*</env-entry>\s*?\n 
\s*-->:
 <env-entry>
     <env-entry-name>solr/home</env-entry-name>
         <env-entry-value>/home/solr</env-entry-value>
     <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
 </env-entry>
:gx' "$@"
```

I added all sorts of spaces (but didn't bother with testing tabs or stray newlines, etc) to the ends and everything seemed to work OK.  May I say "I hate trailing spaces".  And, in my book, it is worth spending time ensuring that files don't have trailing spaces — they cause confusion (I call this question as a witness for the prosecution).  Email signatures are preceded by dash-dash-blank-CRLF (or dash-dash-blank-LF); I hate this.  However, I can't fix the standard easily.

Comment: Well, first of all this is a great, detailed answer and works as you described. But, unfortunately, if I try this with my file it doesn't work. If I copy/paste the part from my file below the content of your data file, it looks [like this](http://pastebin.com/gPtLZRVD). I can't find any difference but executing the shell script only the top one gets replaced. If I exchange both, only the bottom one is replaced. Second, if I wanted to replace the file and add the -i option in the shell file, it says "No such file or directory." Do you have an idea?

Comment: Does your file have CRLF line endings, perhaps?  What does `file your-file` say?  _[…time passeth…pastebin is visited…]_ The trouble is that the first `<!--` line has a space after the second dash.  That can be dealt with.

Comment: I should get some glasses. I checked the line endings for white spaces but apparently I missed one. Thanks! What about the -i option?

Comment: Not sure.  I ran `bash xx.sh -i data` which adds the `-i` to the Perl command line, and sure enough it worked fine for me.  What could be going wrong?  File names with spaces, tabs, newlines in them and not using `"$@"` in the shell script can lead to that problem.  The 'No such file or directory' message doesn't include the file name that isn't found, does it?  (It's lousy error message generation if that is the case: [`perror()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/perror.html) has a lot to answer for. You always want to know the name of the file that is missing.)

Comment: Ehm, I don't know why and I can't reconstruct it, but now it's working. Strange.. But don't bother with it. However, you are right in that the error message did not contain the file name ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat pattern.txt 
<!--
    <env-entry>
       <env-entry-name>solr/home</env-entry-name>
       <env-entry-value>/put/your/solr/home/here</env-entry-value>
       <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
    </env-entry>
-->

$ cat replace.txt
<!--
    <env-entry>
       <env-entry-name>solr/home</env-entry-name>
       <env-entry-value>/home/solr</env-entry-value>
       <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
    </env-entry>
-->

$ perl -0777pe '$pattern=`cat pattern.txt`; s/\Q$pattern\E/`cat replace.txt`/e' -i /usr/share/tomcat6/webapps/solr/WEB-INF/web.xml
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the 
code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.